# Using inputs from Excel worksheet to run Access SQL query from vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have tables that are created each month to reflect that month's records. I have created vba code that runs a query in excel on multiple months to show changes, new adds, etc. However, I would like the user to be able to choose the two months they would like to compare from an excel drop down box. I am struggling to create dynamic SQL that can do this. Below is my attempted code

```
`Private Sub ADO_New()

Dim DBFullName As String
Dim Cnct As String, Src As String
Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Col As Integer
Dim vCurrentMonth As Variant
Dim vPriorMonth As Variant
Dim wSummary As Worksheet

Set wSummary = Worksheets("Summary")
vCurrentMonth = wSummary.Range("Current_Month").Value
vPriorMonth = wSummary.Range("Prior_Month").Value

Worksheets("New").Cells.ClearContents
DBFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Guardian_CensusDB.accdb"


Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Cnct = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Cnct = Cnct & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Cnct

Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset

With Recordset


 Src = "SELECT * FROM [vCurrentMonth] LEFT JOIN [vPriorMonth] ON     
 [vCurrentMonth].[Plan Number] = [vPriorMonth].[Plan Number]" & _
       "WHERE ((([vPriorMonth].[Plan Number]) Is Null))"



.Open Source:=Src, ActiveConnection:=Connection

For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
Sheets("New").Range("A1").Offset(0, Col).Value = _
Recordset.Fields(Col).Name
Next

Sheets("New").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Recordset

End With


Set Recordset = Nothing

Connection.Close
Set Connection = Nothing



End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the variables into your string:

```
Src = "SELECT * FROM [" & vCurrentMonth & "] LEFT JOIN [" & vPriorMonth & "] ON     
 [" & vCurrentMonth & "].[Plan Number] = [" & vPriorMonth & "].[Plan Number]" & _
       "WHERE ((([" & vPriorMonth & "].[Plan Number]) Is Null))"
```

Comment: Thank you Rory!!! I just started writing vba/sql code last month so I figured it was something simple.